# How to query the Parse Server to make the Parse local datastore up to date in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have pinned a parse object in my parse local datastore and I have saved it to the parse server. I have changed some data of that object directly through parse dashboard. Now how to make my parse local datastore to update to those changes?

Comment: They have an example in the Android documentation, simply query, unpin old, pin new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some sort of "refresh" button to your UI that updates your local `ParseObject` by calling [ParseObject.fetch()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#fetch()).